# is.readUTF() not recieving message

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

For the chat program in android side I am sending message via DataInput stream as

```
Socket sck = new Socket();
sck.connect(new InetAddress("192.168.1.91",1500),2000);

if(sck.isConnected())
{
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(sck.getOutputStream());
    os.writeUTf(msg);
    System.out.println("Message sent");
}
```

and on the Server side My code is

```
ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(1500);
Socket sock = serv.accept();
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream);    

String ans = is.readUTF();
System.out.println("Got"+ans);
```

But on server side it seems it does not received anything and still waiting for the message. But on client side It shows message sent.

Here is my full code.

```
package in.prasilabs.eagleeye;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class EagleClient extends Thread
{

    public int ret = 0;
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private Socket sck;
    private boolean estb = false;
    private DataInputStream is;
    private DataOutputStream os;
    private String rmsg = null;
    private String msg;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String reply;

    Data dt = new Data();

    public EagleClient() 
    {

    }
    public EagleClient(String ip, int port, String username, String password)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        establish();
        if(estb == true)
        {
            sendInfo(username,password);
        }

    }
    public void establish()
    {
        int time_out = 2000;
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("trying to connect");
            sck = new Socket();
            sck.connect(new InetSocketAddress(dt.getIp(),dt.getServerPort()),time_out);
            estb = true;
            System.out.println("Established");

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            ret =0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            ret = 0;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(estb == true)
        {
            try {
                is = new DataInputStream(sck.getInputStream());
                os = new DataOutputStream(sck.getOutputStream());
                dt.setOS(os);
                dt.setIS(is);
                System.out.println("Messages are ready to send");
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                ret = 0;
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    public void sendInfo(String user,String password)
    {
        Data dt = new Data();
        is = dt.getIS();
        os = dt.getOS();
        String drport = Integer.toString(dt.getdrPort());
        try {
            os.writeUTF("logn");
            System.out.println("Sending user info");
            os.writeUTF(dt.getUsername());
            os.writeUTF(dt.getPassword());
            os.writeUTF(drport);
            reply = is.readUTF();
            if(reply.equals("success"))
                dt.setLoginStatus(true);
            else
                dt.setLoginStatus(false);
            System.out.println("ACk recieved");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ret = 0;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public int sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        Data dt = new Data();
        os = dt.getOS();
        is = dt.getIS();
        this.msg = msg;
        try {
            os.writeUTF(msg);
            System.out.println("Client :" +msg);
            recieveMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ret = 0;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public void recieveMessage()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to get acknowledgement");
                sck.setSoTimeout(2000);
                rmsg = is.readUTF();
                if(rmsg.equals(msg))
                {
                    System.out.println("Ack recvd" +rmsg);
                    ret = 1;
                }
                else if(!msg.equalsIgnoreCase(rmsg))
                {
                    //sendMessage();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    System.out.println("Retrying");
                    rmsg = is.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Ack recvd" +rmsg);
                    ret = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Message not recieved");
                    ret = 0;
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ret = 0;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: do you not have a while loop in your server? how do you ensure that it is always waiting for connections?

Comment: @Adeeb. Yes until connection is there I have a while loop at ans = is.readUTf()

Comment: Try os.flush() after the writeUTF

Comment: @laune `DataOutputStreams` don't need flushing unless they are layered over streams that do, i.e. `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: `Socket.isConnected()` doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, it doesn't test the state of the connection. It only tells you whether *you* connected *this `Socket.`* Testing it immediately afer calling `Socket.connect()` is completely pointless. It will always return `true` unless an exception is thrown, in which case the test is unreachable.

Comment: @Prasanna I don't believe this. Either your client didn't connect or this isn't the real code.

Comment: @EJP. I using the client as thread to initialize and calling its function/method to send particular message

Comment: Meaningless. Is this the real code or not? If not, what is the real code? The code you've posted does not behave as described.

Comment: @EJP. I attached the full code for the client

Comment: Fine. Where is the Data class? And how can a *new* instance of Data possibly contain the InputStream and OutputStream that were set on a *prior* instance of Data? And what exceptions are being thrown? On the evidence here you're getting a NullPointerException in the client which you have failed to tell us about.

Comment: @EJP. No exception are thrown. The outputstream sends messages without any exception but the inputstream still waiting. the inputstream works for a single time only.

Comment: I repeat. Where is the `Data` class? How do you expect people to help you with your code when you don't post it all?

Comment: I am sorry guys. It's not a problem with this. Code. .. there is some other technical mistake. Overall this one is a working code. I am sorry

Answer (score -3):

Try to use something like this:

```
String message = "";

while (!"end".equals(message)) {
    if (is.available() != 0) {
        message = dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I checked this - working. Server must be up before client will send message.

Comment: I suggested direction only. Not a complete solution.

Comment: The problem - server must print message from client. My portion of help will solve the problem.

Comment: @laune, and what is the problem in this case? Why minus?

Comment: Yes - not optimal, yes - it is bad approah, but it solves the problem in question above. I don't understand people like you.

Comment: Consider: server sends several String values, with delays in between. Client receives first message, but then available() returns 0 (server hasn't sent 2nd String yet) and the while loop just iterates and iterates and iterates all the time. Google "polling" and "active waiting for i/o".

Comment: There is simply *no reason* to avoid blocking and loop needlessly when you have a blocking readUTF which *does* the waiting for you.

Comment: I know! I know that this is big pressure on CPU. But I suggested direction only! Do you undestand?

Comment: This is an abuse of `available()`. It isn't a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. It also doesn't solve the problem. It just introduces a CPU-smoking spin loop. It also doesn't cease smoking the CPU at end of stream.

Comment: @laune You did indeed. There are few if any correct uses of `available()`, and this isn't one of them.